# Overwrite styles for PrimeNG's FileUpload component to look like regular file upload field

Tags: css, angular, primeng

I was looking into PrimeNG's FileUpload component. Can we somehow transform it to function as a 'regular' file input field (i.e. 'Choose' button + file information only; preferably in one line)?
We would not need upload functionality and a progress bar, but drag and drop would be great.
Can we do it using only CSS on a file upload component (hiding 'Upload' and 'Cancel' buttons, moving the 'Choose' button in same line as file info)? If yes, how?

Answer (score 4):

Sure you can, this is an primeng fileupload styling example.

```
/* FileUpload */
.ui-fileupload-choose.ui-button, .ui-fileupload-choose.ui-button .ui-widget, .ui-fileupload-choose.ui-button .ui-state-default {
      background-color: #0275d8;
      border: 1px solid #0275d8;
      color: #ffffff;
}

.ui-fileupload-choose.ui-button.ui-state-hover, .ui-fileupload-choose.ui-button.ui-state-focus, .ui-fileupload-choose.ui-button.ui-state-active {
      background-color: #025aa5;
      border-color: #01549b;
}
```

And you can always look for documentation:

http://primefaces.org/primeng/#/fileupload

At the bottom of that page there is a section called styling.